# Javascript function is not accessing the global scope?

Tags: javascript, function

I wanted to create a simple input field that takes the value of what was inputed to calculate the area of a triangle and I noticed something with my function.
I noticed that for some reason my function could not access the variables that was created in the global scope. like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

input 1: <input type="input" placeholder="Side a" id="sideA"> <br>
input 2: <input type="input" placeholder="Side b"  id="sideB"><br>
input 3: <input type="input" placeholder="Side c" id="sideC"><br>
<button onclick=" AreaResults()"> Calculate</button>

<p id="P_result">

    The area of the triangle is:
</p>
<script >

var side_a = document.getElementById("sideA").value;
     var side_b = document.getElementById("sideB").value;
     var side_c = document.getElementById("sideC").value;

var Allsides = side_c + side_b + side_a;
var perimeter = Allsides/2;
var area = Math.sqrt(( perimeter*(perimeter-side_a)*(perimeter-side_b)*(perimeter-side_c)));


function AreaResults(){


    var resultsInput = document.getElementById("P_result");
    resultsInput.append(area);

}



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

After moving them into the function like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

input 1: <input type="input" placeholder="Side a" id="sideA"> <br>
input 2: <input type="input" placeholder="Side b"  id="sideB"><br>
input 3: <input type="input" placeholder="Side c" id="sideC"><br>
<button onclick=" AreaResults()"> Calculate</button>

<p id="P_result">

    The area of the triangle is:
</p>
<script >



function AreaResults(){

var side_a = document.getElementById("sideA").value;
     var side_b = document.getElementById("sideB").value;
     var side_c = document.getElementById("sideC").value;

var Allsides = side_c + side_b + side_a;
var perimeter = Allsides/2;
var area = Math.sqrt(( perimeter*(perimeter-side_a)*(perimeter-side_b)*(perimeter-side_c)));


    var resultsInput = document.getElementById("P_result");
    resultsInput.append(area);

}



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works just fine.
I do not understand because I thought functions can access all the variable in the global scope

Comment: How do you know you can't access them?

Comment: the code does not work unless I have it written within the function

Answer (score 6):

You're accessing the variables just fine.

However, you set them before the user typed anything (when the page loaded), so they're empty.